# Pass all input one page to other site's page

Tags: php

I have a form. I wanna take inputs and pass another page. For ex.

```
site1.com/asd.php?input1=xx&input2=yy
```

I want redirect this.

```
site2.com/asd.JSP?input1=xx&input2=yy
```

I searched in stackoverflow but all about one php page to another php. I want php page to jsp page. I used this code but it is not passing inputs.

```
<form id="myForm" action="site2.com/asd.jsp" 
method="get">
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $a => $b) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($a).'" 
value="'.htmlentities($b).'">';
    }
?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: But  I want use php page first

Comment: O right, I see. So you may find cURL useful for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first URL is GET request but in foreach you used the POST data for fill the hidden fields.

Change the foreach:

```
foreach ($_GET as $a => $b)
```

Comment: Thank you. it is perfect